# scroll div depending on mouse position. Optimisation help?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have this javascript code that scrolls a div depending on the mouse position.

Ive got the code working, the problem is its a bit jittery. I was wondering if anybody could give me advice on how to optimise it so it runs smoothly!

To view the code please visit my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ENhwT/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realised i was going WELL too far with this, and the solution was easy.

You calculate the new scroll position based on the EXACT mouse Position... Code Follows:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var container = $("#PortfolioReel");
    var elem = $("#PortfolioReel div");
    var max_pos = container.width();
    var max_scroll = elem.width() - max_pos;
    var differential = max_scroll / max_pos;
    $("#PortfolioReel").mousemove(function(e){
        var pos = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) + 1;
        var scr = Math.round(pos * differential);           
        container.scrollLeft(scr);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You set the position in fixed large steps, so it's 'jumping'. You have to iterate in smaller steps until you reach the target position.

You shouldn't use six fixed position values, but calculate new values in timesteps.

You could use something like this to make a smoother transition:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

#### Sample

Something like this should be working:

```
elem.animate({
        scrollLeft: current + 25
    }, 500, function() {
        // Animation complete.
  });
```

Comment: i cant get the animate to work, would this be the correct usage? elem.animate({scrollLeft:current + 25});

Comment: `elem.animate({scrollLeft:'+=25'},someDuration);`

Comment: Of course you need to change some of your code to make this work in your code logic. -- Without animate you have to interpolate the scrollTo in smaller steps yourself in a loop. -- It may be smoother to disable the scrollbar itself and set CSS positions instead of using `scrollTo` you'll have to try this yourself-